# jenkins - unit test error

Tags: xcode, jenkins

Iam trying unit test with jenkins, but I've get an error: 
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE

I found some solutions, but if test is FAILURE.

My test is SUCCEEDED.

```
** TEST SUCCEEDED **

2016-09-18 17:34:00.850958 TestBuild[10328:110818] subsystem: 
com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, 
persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, 
generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, 
enable_private_data: 0

Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.203
Test Suite 'UnitTests.xctest' started at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.203
Test Suite 'UnitTests' started at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.204
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Test Case '-[UnitTests.UnitTests testHm]' started.
Test Case '-[UnitTests.UnitTests testHm]' passed (0.003 seconds).
Test Suite 'UnitTests' passed at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.208.
Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.003 (0.004) seconds
Test Suite 'UnitTests.xctest' passed at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.208.
 Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.003 (0.005) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' passed at 2016-09-18 17:34:01.209.
 Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.003 (0.006) seconds
[Test] $ /bin/sh -xe   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/hudson8849374170526692527.sh
+ cd TestBuild/test-reports/
+ touch '*.xml'
Recording test results
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

Any idea or advices, please?

Comment: Are the XML files being read by the results publisher the same ones that are written by your tests?

Comment: yes. I tried 100 next variants, but nothing..

Comment: Perhaps show the configuration?